# How to write a Custom Policy in Mule4 with keyvalues which validates each incoming header requests

Tags: validation, request-headers, mule4

I want to write a custom policy in Mule4. The UI would be keyvalue pairs (look similar to InboundHeaders in HeaderInjection policy). So I used keyvalue as a type in Configuration.yaml in the custom policy. Now I want to check the value for each corresponding key should match with the value that I would put in the attributes.headers section in each api. If all the values that I will put in the custom policy matches with the corresponding attributes.headers in postman then only it will pass otherwise it will fail.. I could do it with a single text box with string type.. but how do I do with keyvalues, I.e., multiple headers and its values

Comment: Hi, the question is unclear. Please edit to clarify it and to make the question explicit.

Comment: I edited it.. could you please let me know if its clear

Comment: It is much better. Each key should match an HTTP header?

Comment: Yes.. the value that would come in the header... for example please refer to the below code for single string: